# Shopify asset not loading

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to include a JavaScript file (named StoreLocator.js) from my Shopify assets by using the URL filters as explained in the Shopify documentation (see https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/url-filters).

First of all, I uploaded the JavaScript file to the assets folder. I noticed during debugging that the uploaded JavaScript file is accessible under the following URL:

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0551/8009/9636/t/6/assets/StoreLocator.js

I was able to debug this, because I used the same JavaScript file and the same URL filter in a previous project and it worked just fine. Therefore I could see, that Shopify uses this URL to load the JavaScript file.

However, by using the following URL-filter in the new project.

```
{{ 'StoreLocator.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

it generates the following URL which is incorrect (note the part `/t/6` vs `/t9`.

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0551/8009/9636/t/9/assets/StoreLocator.js

Unfortunately I could not find any documentation about the URLs that the Shopify CDN generates. In the present case it would be interesting to know why the URL changed from `/t/6` to `/t9`.

Can someone explain why the URL filter does not point to the correct URL?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the file is present in your theme assets folder? The liquid file is correct, the generated asset url is based on your store, you shouldn't be require to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work:-

Make sure your StoreLocator.js file is present in Assets folder

```
<script  src="{{ 'StoreLocator.js' | asset_url }}" ></script>
```

After using this you have to check this url in 'view page source' and click this url and check url code in browser and in any code editor